# Можно ли обойти ограничение на запись на ExSDcard?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Пишу простую программу для шифрования данных в Android. Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что нет доступа на запись к exSDcard устройств. После долгих поисков в интернете узнал, что с Android 4.4.2 введен запрет на запись на внешние носители.  Собственно, вопрос заключается в том, что можно ли без получения root прав записать файл в exSDcard директорию и каким способом?

P.S. В Manifest.xml premissions прописаны

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тема уже мусолилась мильон тыщ раз - тем не менее повторюсь:

> можно ли без получения root прав записать файл в exSDcard директорию и каким способом?

Да, можно. Как пишет документация:

> Starting in Android 4.4, the owner, group and modes of files on external storage devices are now synthesized based on directory structure. This enables apps to manage their package-specific directories on external storage without requiring they hold the broad WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. For example, the app with package name com.example.foo can now freely access Android/data/com.example.foo/ on external storage devices with no permissions.

Если вкратце, то приложение может создать свой приватный каталог на карте памяти и писать туда, но писать на карту памяти куда угодно запрещено (читать кстати, можно).

Методы обхода сего несколько раз появлялись в сети, но Google патчами закрывал эти дырки. На некоторых моделях разных устройств, тем не менее, разрешения даются и давались, например Samsung при запросе `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` автоматически дает разрешение `WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE` и если медиа сторидж на карте, то можно писать в каталог медиа. В прошивках Cyanogen также есть разрешение на запись на карту.

Впрочем в версии Android 5.0 появилась официальная дырка в заборе, а именно в каталог получаемый с помощью метода `getExternalMediaDirs()` - можно и писать и читать безо всяких пермишенов.